# Align tables top

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have three tables. When they are all filled with data (10 rows) they look fine. See picture
[image]

When, however, the max capacity (i.e. 10 rows) hasn't been reached, the tables gets centered.
[image]

I want to keep the alignment top as in the first picture and also the buttons on the bottom. Is there any simple style to do this? My HTML looks like this

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table id="SomeTableContainer">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="prev1"><<</button>
            <button id="next1">>></button>
            <button id="create1">Create</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="SomeOtherTableContainer">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="prev2"><<</button>
            <button id="next2">>></button>
            <button id="create2">Create</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="OtherTableContainer">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button id="prev3"><<</button>
            <button id="next3">>></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi now add **td** `valign="top"`

As like this

```
<td valign="top">
```

or
Used in

**css**

```
td{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that easy. Thanks! (I will mark your answer in a few minutes. Apparently I have to wait 10 min. before I can do that.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your first TR:

```
<tr valign="top"></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

add style

```
td { vertical-align: top;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td valign="top">
                <table id="SomeOtherTableContainer">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button id="prev2"><<</button>
                <button id="next2">>></button>
                <button id="create2">Create</button>
            </td>
```